# How to change the inbuilt Laravel 5 authentication system?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5 for the first time. I have worked with 4 earlier. Laravel ships with a AuthenticatesAndRegisterUsers.php file which handles most of the stuff and makes registering and logging in users very easy.

I wanted to tweak this file to suit my own needs such as not logging the user and instead sending them an activation link and checking if the user is activation on login.

**postLogin**

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            if(!$this->auth->user()->activated)
            {
                $this->auth->logout();
                return redirect($this->loginPath())
                        ->withErrors(['activated' => 'Your account is not activated yet. <br /> Please check your email for activation link.']);
            }

            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
                    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                    ->withErrors([
                        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                    ]);
    }
```

**postRegister**

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        $this->registrar->create($request->all());

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withErrors(['activated' => 'Activation link has been sent to your email address.']);
    }
```

This is working like a charm for me but later I realized that I had edited the vendor files to suit my needs as this file is inside the vendor folder. And of course it does not commit on version control.

So my question is how to use the Laravel 5 authentication system but suit my needs too in the process. Could I extend this class somehow and override the methods or would I have to write my own class completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override those methods in the `AuthController` (or whatever controller that uses the trait). Simply copy both functions over and you're good to go.