# Laravel 5: After login the user is was redirected to /home. How to change that?

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, laravel-5

I have created my own root page (`/`) as well as my register page (`/cadastrar`). My next step was to allow the user to login and update their information. For that I just used laravel's login page (`/auth/login`). It works fine and when I login I get redirected to `/home`. At this point my problem arises: I can not go to any other page (`/`) (`/cadastrar`). **I always get redirected back to `/home`**.

I did not change any configuration regarding login or redirections so what could be wrong and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** At my (`/`) I have a Sign in link. When I click, I go to (`/auth/login`). I put my email and password, press login and it redirects me to (`/home`) saying that I'm logged in. Now I want to go to (`/`) or any other page, but it always redirect me to (`/home`). Thats my problem.
My plan was to let the users update their information only if they are logged in, but now I can't go anywhere.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916117/how-to-change-the-inbuilt-laravel-5-authentication-system might be helpful

Answer (score 7):

In `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` on line 38 change:

```
return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
```

to

```
return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
```

Comment: Hi @Pawel Bieszczad, I already tried that, but Firefox just shows the message _The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete._

Comment: according to this google [result](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/938531) it might be a problem with cookies. try clearing them out for your website. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: And even if it works, it will just always redirect me to (`/`). I want to go to any page and, once there, check if the user is authenticated or not and, if so, show a update button.

Comment: I cleared the browser cookies, but still got the error. Just tried firefox. I'll download Chrome and try.

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want to check if user is logged in when he sgoing to a page xyz, if not show him the login page and if he logs in redirect him back to the page he was trying to view (xyz)? If thats the case you should use the `intended()` method. Check out the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#introduction) and scroll to manual authentication

Comment: You can choose the path you want the user to go after the update `return new RedirectResponse(url('/any/path/you/want'));`

Comment: I tried that and it shows me the error I told you before. But now I think the problem is with firefox. I'm trying to download chrome and it always crashes. Thanks for the tip. I'll try install here.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I went into my `WelcomeController` and commented out the line in the `__construct` function that assigned this page only to guests the redirection problem was gone:

```
//$this->middleware('guest');
```