# Laravel5 OldMiddleware The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm just taking the first look at laravel5
so with a new install I'm starting playing around
(as usual :) )

*php artisan make:middleware OldMiddleware*

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OldMiddleware {

    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->input('age') < 200)
        {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}

<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
        'App\Http\Middleware\OldMiddleware',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    ];

}
```

when I hit

```
http://localhost/l5/public/
```

there is a redirect to

```
http://localhost/l5/public/home
```

with the message

*The page isn't redirecting properly*

What's the problem ?

I've just tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/30116118 but still not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the `$routeMiddleware`..

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'home' => 'App\Http\Middleware\OldMiddleware',
];
```

and in your route..

```
Route::get('/',  ['middleware' => 'home'], function() {
    return "blah";
}
Route::get('/home', function() {
    return "home";
}
```

Then if you go to `example.com/` it go to the middleware and redirect's you to `/home`.

The `The page isn't redirecting properly` comes because a loop occurs.

**PS:** If you don't want the built in login etc. you can do

```
artisan fresh
```

..sometimes it's better to start fresh if you just want to playing around! ;)

Comment: thanks :) bye the way 'OldMiddleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\OldMiddleware', should be 'home' => 'App\Http\Middleware\OldMiddleware', but still doesn't work :(

Comment: So if I put it only in the $routeMiddleware it works but it doesn't work in Global Middleware do you know why ?

Comment: I think it's because it's redirect you everywhere.. so if you are on `/home` it will redirect you anyway. But you can write something else in the middleware like `dd('blah);` instead a redirect and it should work! ;)