# How to hook into laravel built-in login to add email verified check

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel 5.1 I am trying to modify my login procedure to require that a user has confirmed their email before they can log in. I have the process of confirming email working, but where do I put the check on login attempt to verify that email_confirmed is true?

My login route is like this:

```
Route::post('login', [
    'as'   => 'login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'
]);
```

But the login function isn't in authcontroller, it's attached to it via the trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers; Which basically incorporates the trait AuthenticatesUsers which actually contains getLogin and postLogin functions.

This is deep into the framework files so I shouldn't be messing with those. Besides if I update laravel anything I put there is likely to be overwritten anyway.

So where can I put my check when a user tries to login to only allow it if they've confirmed their email address?
Maybe somehow in Middleware/Authenticate.php (just guessing...)

I looked at this question: [How to change the inbuilt Laravel 5 authentication system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916117/how-to-change-the-inbuilt-laravel-5-authentication-system?rq=1) which says you can override that postLogin function by copying it into authController, but I still don't see where I check if user->email_confirmed is true if I do that.

Here's the postLogin default from laravel:

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's what I did:
Copied above postLogin function to the AuthController
Added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Replaced:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }
```

With:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $credentials['email'], 'password'=>$credentials['password'],
    'disabled_at' => null, 'email_confirmed' => true], $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
}
```

This now checks that email is confirmed and user is not disabled as part of authenticating.